# Query over unknown variable

Tags: javascript, variables, animation, numbers, increment

I'm currently learning Javascript and trying out a some code.  I have put together a Fiddle that makes a number animate from 0 to a 1000.  It works fine, but I had to add some extra lines of code I sourced from other scripts I have seen to get it exactly how I want.

There are two fiddles I have setup:

[With the variable](http://jsfiddle.net/zeNpU/2/) - Runs nice and smooth an animates when the browser is scrolling or still.

[Without the variable](http://jsfiddle.net/zeNpU/4/) - The numbers animate only when the browser is still, and pauses when its scrolling.

The variables I add to get the desired result are:

```
if (!run && isScrolledIntoView('#visible')) {
///&
run=true;
//&
var run = false;
```

Can someone explain to me why I have to have these to get it to run with the browser scrolling? I have tried to look around the web to find out what they do; but to no avail.  I would rather understand exactly what it does than just code-and-hope, even if it does work.

This may seem obvious, but I'm trying to learn. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't open. Try to fix it.

Comment: @Maximus thanks for that, but when I click the links they work fine for me in Chrome and Firefox, strange it doesn't work in Safari?.  Do you manage to reach the site or does it give you an error?

Comment: I use Chrome as well. The browser can't reach website.

Comment: @Maximus does this one work? http://jsfiddle.net/zeNpU/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. With the variable `run` in is place the code execution enters the `if (!run && isScrolledIntoView('#visible'))` block only once when you scroll first.

```
var run = false;
```

Evaluates to `TRUE` in the if block, so the code execution gets inside. Than it changes the variable to 'true', which in the if block evaluates to `FALSE` so that code execution doesn't get inside the block;
Add `alert('hello');` inside the if block and you'll see for yourself.

As a side note:
One could've named the variable `alreadyStarted` instead of ambiguos `run`, which would save you from trouble figuring out what it does. Try to write obvious code yourself :). This is an excellent reading for the excellent practices [Code complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670)

Comment: Much appreciated Maximus! It makes perfect sense now.

Comment: one last question, why is there a ! before the run variable?

Comment: It converts to the opposite, so if you have `var alreadyStarted = true`, than `!alreadyStarted` evaluates to false. You may also encounter `!!`, which is a way to convert a variable to a boolean value

Comment: That was going to be my guess but wanted to check, thank you again!